# Ionic4 / Angular - Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc' on Ionic serve

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

i got stuck on an **issue** after installing a `cordova plugin` and using "`npm audit fix`".

Now if im trying to `serve my app`, i get this message:

> [ng] An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module
>   '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc' [ng] See
>   "C:\Users\Jorden\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-1VnycD\angular-errors.log" for
>   further details.
>
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).
>
> The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error
>   details.

I tried many solutions i found, but none of these worked for me..

Here is the `angular-errors.log`:

> [error] Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Jorden\Desktop\Ionic\myApp\node_modules@ngtools\webpack
>   \src\ngcc_processor.js:10:16)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Jorden\Desktop\Ionic\myApp\node_modules@ngtools\webpack  \src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:23:26)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)

And my **package.json**:

> {   "name": "myApp",   "version": "0.0.1",   "author": "Ionic
>   Framework",   "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",   "scripts":
>   {
>       "ng": "ng",
>       "start": "ng serve",
>       "build": "ng build",
>       "test": "ng test",
>       "lint": "ng lint",
>       "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
>       "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
>       "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
>       "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
>       "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
>       "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
>       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
>       "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
>       "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
>       "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.18.0",
>       "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.14.0",
>       "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
>       "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
>       "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
>       "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
>       "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
>       "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
>       "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
>       "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.6.0",
>       "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.0",
>       "core-js": "^2.5.4",
>       "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
>       "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
>       "tslib": "^1.9.0",
>       "woocommerce-api": "^1.4.2",
>       "zone.js": "~0.8.29"   },   "devDependencies": {
>       "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.803.21",
>       "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
>       "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.3.9",
>       "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^8.3.21",
>       "@angular/cli": "^8.3.21",
>       "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
>       "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
>       "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
>       "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
>       "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
>       "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
>       "@types/node": "^12.6.8",
>       "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
>       "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
>       "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
>       "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
>       "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
>       "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
>       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
>       "karma": "~4.1.0",
>       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
>       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
>       "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
>       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
>       "protractor": "~5.4.0",
>       "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
>       "tslint": "~5.17.0",
>       "typescript": "~3.1.6"   },   "description": "An Ionic project",   "cordova": {
>       "plugins": {
>         "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
>         "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-device": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
>       },
>       "platforms": [
>         "ios",
>         "android",
>         "browser"
>       ]   } }

Hope you guys can help me :)

Comment: Stop all running processes, remove node_modules, run npm install again .. check for any weird imports in your editor

Comment: Everything done, still same Errormessage. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Did you try installing the module alone using `npm i <moduleName>`?

Comment: If i delete node_modules and try to use 'npm i @angular/compiler-cli/' , it says "error Could not install from "@angular\compiler-cli" as it does not contain a package.json file"

Comment: Fixed it now by doing these steps:  
1.Changing version of **angular/compiler** to 7.2.2 in devDependencies
2. Changing version of **angular/compiler-cli** to 7.2.2 in devDependencies
3. deleting **package.json.lock**
4.**npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular**
5.**npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.13.0**

Dont know if this a good solution..

Answer (score 1):

For IONIC 4 the following downgrades worked for me.

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.25
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24
```